# How to add form elements using javascript that contains php?

Tags: javascript, php

This is my code:

```
Category:
<select name='category'>
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<option name={$row[0]} value={$row[1]}>{$row[1]}</option>";
}} ?>
</select> <br><br>

Quantity:
<input type='text' name='quantity' onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"><br><br>

Price:
<input type='text' name='price' onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"><br><br>
<a href='#' onclick="addformfield()">Insert another item</a>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
```

When user clicks on Insert another item, I want to again add Category, Quantity and Price as seen above using Javascript.

Please help.

Comment: you did not mention what is wrong with your current code

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: @meda I cannot figure out how to fetch item from database and insert in select option using javascript.

Comment: your form elements will not "contain php", the php will have already run when the page is rendered after that there is nothing else dealing with php.

Comment: You can't just add php elements while on the client side and expect it to work. They are two separate concepts that don't really know about each other. you will need to use AJAX to get the information you need from the server (what would be the php you want to place) and then insert proper html elements on the client side.

Comment: @scrappedcola So I need to fetch data using AJAX and then insert in the select field? Can you help me out with that as I am not well-versed using php with AJAX.

Comment: This tutorial might be a good start. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php for others i would lookup "php And ajax".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick solution without the need of an AJAX request.

```
<?php
$categories = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $categories[$row[0]] = $row[1];
    }
}
?>

<div id="groups"></div>
<a href='#' id="insert-another-item">Insert another item</a>

<script>    
var categories = <?= json_encode($categories) ?>,
    groupId = 0;

$(function() {
    insertGroup();
    $('#insert-another-item').on('click', function() {
        insertGroup();
        return false;
    });     
}); 

function insertGroup() {
    group = '<div class="group">' 
              + '<select name="groups[' + groupId + '][category]"></select>'
              + '<input type="text" name="groups[' + groupId + '][quantity]">'
              + '<input type="text" name="groups[' + groupId + '][price]">'
          + '</div>';

    $('#groups').append(group);

    $.each(categories, function(key, value) {
        $('select[name="groups[' + groupId + '][category]"]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
    });

    groupId++;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. But I can't get it working. 
It fetches data but after clicking on the link the elements are not getting appended to the groups.

Comment: Did you include jQuery? Anyway it works, you can check it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cgkEi